# Javascript Object.values order guarantee

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const CONSTANT = Object.freeze({a: 1, b: 2});
```

Is it guaranteed that `Object.values(CONSTANT)` will return `[1, 2]`?

On [MDN's doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), it says it follows `for...in` which iterates in in original insertion order.

On some [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order), it claims order is guaranteed for `getOwnPropertyNames` but not `for...in`.

Also, what implementation could they use to guarantee insertion order? If a sorted collection of some sort is used to track the order, wouldn't it result in O(log n) complexity for insertion/deletion of object properties?

Comment: I think the bottom line here is: You are NOT guaranteed that the order will be [1,2], nor that it will it be the insertion order. It might be either [1,2] or [2,1], but you ARE guaranteed the order of `Object.values` will be the same as `for...in` and that it will not change, unless the object itself changes.

Comment: @K. Kirsz [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) says `The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in original insertion order.`

Comment: MDN's statements are not canonical.

Comment: The question isn't specific to Object.values. This entirely depends on how object properties order is handled by JS engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let v of ['a','b']) {
    console.log(CONSTANT[v])
}
```

Would guarantee the order.

Comment: Well yes, if you use an array to control the iteration.  The question is asking about iterating over the properties of an object directly.